# Lombok delombok option doesn't generate code for @Nonnull check

Tags: java, lombok

So, what I'm trying to do, is to generate null check code with delombok feature, but it doesn't work:

```
c:\lib>java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p LombokTest.java
package com.some.test;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LombokTest implements Serializable {

        public String text;

        public LombokTest( @NonNull Object text) {
                this.text = text.toString();
        }

        public int setText( @ NonNull String anotherText) {
                this.text = anotherText;
                return anotherText.length();
        }
}

c:\lib>java -jar lombok.jar -version
v1.16.6 "Candid Duck"

c:\lib>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After some testing locally, I'd say that definitely looks like a bug in delombok.  Have you put up a message on their forums yet?

Comment: Ok, reported. Is there any workaround, which I can use, before this issue is fixed?

Comment: If there is, I haven't found one yet.  For what it's worth, you might be able to manually replace the @NonNull annotation and drop a call to `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(T obj, String message)` in your code.  It'll throw an NPE with whatever error message you supply if `obj` is null, just like @NonNull does.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, David! It's possible, of course, but my goal is to get rid of all those checks and replace them with annotations only.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug, I reported this one, and it was kindly fixed:
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/950
There is no workaround for this one. You can only wait for a new lombok build.

Comment: The issue is closed, but the bug is still present.